# Definition of the union of structures?

Tags: logic, definition

Using the logic definition of a structure as a set coupled with finitary functions and relations, what is the definition of the union of two structures $\mathfrak{A}_1 \cup \mathfrak{A}_2$?

I encountered this in a discussion of preservation, where $\mathfrak{A}_1$ is an elementary substructure of $\mathfrak{A}_2$, if that makes any difference.

(I hate to ask such a basic question, but I can't find this anywhere)

Comment: AFAIK $\mathfrak{A}_1 \cup \mathfrak{A}_2$ is defined only if $\mathfrak{A}_1, \mathfrak{A}_2$ have an upper bound, say $\mathfrak{A}$. Then the union is $\mathfrak{A}$ with functions and relations restricted to unions of corresponding sorts of $\mathfrak{A}_1, \mathfrak{A}_2$.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I could find was at the bottom of page 144 of the following:

http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1970.1/Main/icm1970.1.0141.0150.ocr.pdf

It makes sense that the models be related in some way as described in the above reference. For instance, if A is a model of $\phi$ and B is a model of $\neg\phi$, there can be no model which is the union of A and B.

Comment: Thanks! The PDF page you mention appears to be a more in-depth version of the topic that led me to ask this question:  That any element of an elementary-substructure chain is an elementary substructure of the chain's union. And happily, the PDF cites references that I'm trying to look up right now.

Comment: Cool! I'm glad it worked out so well.